# Hide floating action button based on admin privilege

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to hide a floating action button for none admin users of my android app. So when I did the code below the FAB gets hidden for all users.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (FirebaseUtil.isAdmin) {
        final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.show();
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ListActivity.this, ItemActivity.class));
            }
        });
}
```

But when I nested the condition inside the FAB as below it gets hidden for none admin after a none admin user clicks it.

```
    final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (FirebaseUtil.isAdmin) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ListActivity.this, ItemActivity.class));
            } else {
                // TODO: Hide FAB for none none-admin users
                fab.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here's the XML, any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @Zoe thanks for the edit, well noted! do you have any other suggestion to help out with the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked if your `isAdmin` method returns the correct value?

Comment: I do not see _fab.show();_

Comment: Is the method IsAdmin async?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `View.setVisibility()`. `FloatingActionButton.show()` or `FloatingActionButton.hide()` will only work if the view has already been laid out as you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton#show)